# CMake shared dll not working after compiling

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion

I've just recently switched from using Visual Studio to CLion as I find it much easier to work in. My biggest problem is that I know nothing about how CMake works and why a very simple project doesn't work for me.

I've have a very small project that makes a .dll file for windows - it's only a few lines plus a link to an API library somewhere on my machine. here's the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(pushpull)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(API_SRC_Files  "D:/Work/API_SRC_Files")
include_directories(
        .
        ${API_SRC_Files}
        ${API_SRC_Files}/Core

)

add_library(pushpull SHARED CPushPull.cpp CPushPull.h PushPull.cpp)
```

There are no warning or erros and compilation seems successful:

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared library pushpull.dll
   Creating library pushpull.lib and object pushpull.exp
   Creating library pushpull.lib and object pushpull.exp
[100%] Built target pushpull

Build finished
```

However, when I go to load the .dll, it is not working and I get a "could not load" type warning from the program for this .dll.

I'm using windows and Visual studio as the tool chain.

My suspicion was something related to compiler flags as I know when using gcc on linux I need to add `-fPIC` so I tried adding this:

```
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```

but that didn't make any difference.

I've also tried:

```
if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS TRUE)
endif()
```

and again, while everything compiles nicely, it still can't be loaded.

I know I must have missed something, most likely in the `CMakeLists` file rather than the project settings, because if I just open up Visual Studio create an empty dll project there and add these files everything works perfectly.

Help appreciated.

## Update

As mentioned in the comments, the error message is vague - it is but that's all that is shown there is noting else. It expects to always be able to load the dll so when it doesn't it just says "could not load %NAME%".

As suggested below, I may not be linking libraries correctly that VS is doing automatically, so I've tried linking with all of those mentioned in the VS project template:

```
target_link_libraries(pushpull kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib)
```

But this also doesn't work. What is noticeable that the CMake dll is only 71kb while the VS one is 73kb. Something is getting omitted?

Comment: Make sure the dll is either in the directory of the program or add the dll directory to the path environment variable.

Comment: Position independent code is only important for static libs you want to link into a dll. You don't need that for dlls. `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` is only relevant for libraries where you don't set the type in `add_library`. Btw: is the dll in the working directory or the path environment var when running the program? Also are both the program and the dll available in the path/working directory 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Yes, the .dll is in the correct working directory. It's in the same location as the one built from VS (which works) but with a different name.

Comment: 'I get a "could not load" type warning from the program for this .dll.' - Quite a *vague* description. Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message** you got.

Comment: Yes, it's very vague but that is all that is displayed. It simple throws up that message when the dll file doesn't work. There is nothing specific to note other than that the dll compiled by CMake in CLIon doesn't work, while the dll compiled from the exact same files with Visual Studio does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `DLL` in `cmake` is similar to creating executable!
You must call `add_library` by `SHARED` flag and list of code files! as you done!

And next you must call `target_link_libraries` after `add_library` command and introduce libraries to link! I see no `target_link_libraries` in your post!

If you do both, check logs carefully and you will find problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228017/discussion-between-jpmorr-and-ali-razmkhah).